# Calculation with DN and metadata in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to implement a calculation in Google earth engine and the necessary parameters are DN (digital number) and other values found in the image metadata (Landsat 8).
The calculation is to obtain the **radiance** TOA (L) = DN*M+A, where M and A are the multiplicative and additive rescaling factors (respectively) for a given band. I tried with band 7 but I don't know if the procedure is correct and if so how to see the results

Here is my code:

```
*var point: Point (-70.26,-17.98)
var spatialFiltered = l8.filterBounds(point);
print('spatialFiltered', spatialFiltered);
var temporalFiltered = spatialFiltered.filterDate('2023-01-01', '2023-01-19');
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_RT/LC08_002072_20131222')
var aoi = ee.Geometry(point).buffer(5000);
Map.addLayer(image.clip(aoi), null, 'image clipped');

//Band7 
var M7= image.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7');
var A7= image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7');
var Q7= image.select('B7'); 

var L7 = M7*Q7+A7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `M7*Q7+A7` doesn't work because it's a client-side function for server-side operations. I recommend you to read about the difference between both in [Client vs. Server Guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

Create a custom function for getting radiance from band 7:

```
var B7radiance = function(img) {
  var mult = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7')));
  var add= ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7')));
  var band= image.select('B7').multiply(mult).add(add).rename('radB7');
  return img.addBands(band);
};
```

Then, if you want to apply it over a image, use it directly:

```
var image_rad7 = B7radiance(image);
```

You can also apply the function over an imageCollection with `.map()`:

```
var spatialFiltered_rad7 = spatialFiltered.map(B7radiance)
```

Also, you can compute radiance over all bands with a single function:

```
var addRadiance = function(img) {
  var mult1 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_1')));
  var mult2 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_2')));
  var mult3 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_3')));
  var mult4 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_4')));
  var mult5 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_5')));
  var mult6 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_6')));
  var mult7 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_7')));
  var mult8 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_8')));
  var mult9 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_9')));
  var mult10 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_10')));
  var mult11 = ee.Image(ee.Number(img.get('RADIANCE_MULT_BAND_11')));
  var add1 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_1')));
  var add2 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_2')));
  var add3 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_3')));
  var add4 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_4')));
  var add5 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_5')));
  var add6 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_6')));
  var add7 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_7')));
  var add8 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_8')));
  var add9 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_9')));
  var add10 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_10')));
  var add11 = ee.Image(ee.Number(image.get('RADIANCE_ADD_BAND_11')));
  var band1 = image.select('B1').multiply(mult1).add(add1).rename('rB1');
  var band2 = image.select('B2').multiply(mult2).add(add2).rename('rB2');
  var band3 = image.select('B3').multiply(mult3).add(add3).rename('rB3');
  var band4 = image.select('B4').multiply(mult4).add(add4).rename('rB4');
  var band5 = image.select('B5').multiply(mult5).add(add5).rename('rB5');
  var band6 = image.select('B6').multiply(mult6).add(add6).rename('rB6');
  var band7 = image.select('B7').multiply(mult7).add(add7).rename('rB7');
  var band8 = image.select('B8').multiply(mult8).add(add8).rename('rB8');
  var band9 = image.select('B9').multiply(mult9).add(add9).rename('rB9');
  var band10 = image.select('B10').multiply(mult10).add(add10).rename('rB10');
  var band11 = image.select('B11').multiply(mult11).add(add11).rename('rB11');
  return img.addBands(band1).addBands(band2).addBands(band3).addBands(band4)
            .addBands(band5).addBands(band6).addBands(band7).addBands(band8)
            .addBands(band9).addBands(band10).addBands(band11);
};

var image_rad = addRadiance(image);

var spatialFiltered_rad = spatialFiltered.map(addRadiance)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked for me, but another question arose; is there a way to visualize the radiance variation in the image in the form of a color palette (as is done with NDVI for example) ?

Comment: Yes, you can set a [color pallete](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization). Although it should be set layer by layer, for VIS layers is higher than NIR layers. Radiance change over time (in summer is higher than winter), so the same color palette won't work for all scenes as well